# OpenCV machine learning error

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am using this script to train 10 photos my self taken with an Iphone with an attempt to tinker around with some facial recognition... 1st attempt at this..

This classifier works just fine:
`LBPHFace = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()`

But these two classifiers, I get an error.. Would anyone have any ideas to research further?? The pixels should be all the same size as all images were taken at the same time with an Iphone... Appreciate any help, thank you...

```
FisherFace = cv2.face.FisherFaceRecognizer_create()
EigenFace = cv2.face.EigenFaceRecognizer_create()
```

***error: (-210) In the Eigenfaces method all input samples (training images) must be of equal size! Expected 2992900 pixels, but was 1329409 pixels. in function cv::face::Eigenfaces::train***

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import pickle

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
image_dir = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "images", "Bob")

haar_face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')
recognizer = cv2.face.EigenFaceRecognizer_create(15)

current_id = 0
label_ids = {}
y_labels = []
x_train = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(image_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith("png") or file.endswith("JPG"):
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            label = os.path.basename(root).replace(" ", "-").lower()
            print(label, path)
            if not label in label_ids:
                label_ids[label] = current_id
                current_id += 1

            id_ = label_ids[label]
            #print(label_ids)
            #y_labels.append(label) # some number
            #x_train.append(path) # verify this image, turn into a NUMPY arrray, GRAY
            pil_image = Image.open(path).convert("L") # grayscale
            #size = (550, 550)
            #final_image = pil_image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
            image_array = np.array(pil_image, "uint8")
            #print(image_array)
            faces = haar_face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image_array, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)

            for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
                roi = image_array[y:y+h, x:x+w]
                x_train.append(roi)
                y_labels.append(id_)


#print(y_labels)
#print(x_train)

with open("pickles/face-labels.pickle", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(label_ids, f)

recognizer.train(x_train, np.array(y_labels))
recognizer.save("recognizers/face-trainner.yml")
```

Comment: Have the program print out the images you're feeding in. Determine the size of each. If you're cutting up the images to train, make sure the cuts are generating equally-sized images.

Comment: Somehow I think my training and test data is not the same size. And Im not really sure where or how this gets implemented into the code... : /

Comment: It may be worth reading the cv2 documentation to determine this, then.

Answer (score -1):

i think you should try this very similar code for training your model:

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import pickle

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/nitish/Desktop/project/s_w/opencv- 
4.1.2/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml') #path of this xml file

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

image_dir = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/home/nitish/Desktop/project/faces/") 
#path of your images file

current_id = 0
label_ids = {}
y_labels = []
x_train = []

count = 0

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(image_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith("jpg"):
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            label = os.path.basename(root).replace(" ", "-").lower()
            # print(label,path)
            if not label in label_ids:
                label_ids[label] = current_id
                current_id += 1
            id_ = label_ids[label]
            pil_image = Image.open(path).convert("L")
            size = (80, 80)
            final_image = pil_image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
            image_array = np.array(final_image, "uint8")
            faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image_array,
                                                  scaleFactor=1.5,
                                                  minNeighbors=5)

            for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                roi = image_array[y:y + h, x:x + w]
                count += 1
                x_train.append(roi)
                # print(id_)
                y_labels.append(id_)

# print(np.array(x_train[0]))
# print(np.array(y_labels))
print(count)
with open("lables.pickle", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(label_ids, f)

recognizer.train(x_train, np.array(y_labels))
recognizer.save('trainer.yml')
print ("Model Training Complete ^-^")
```